# How to fire System.Timers.Timer only once

Tags: multithreading, windows-services, timer, infinite-loop

I am creating a WindowsService which has a Timer bound to an EventHandler which has an infinite loop; I want to be able to fire this Timer once in the service's OnStart() method, then stop the Timer in the service's OnStop(). How can I force the Timer to fire only once?

Also, is this the best design possible for controlling infinite loops within a WindowsService? Would handling it inside another thread (perhaps background thread) be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would handling it inside another thread (perhaps background thread) be better?

Yes.  This sounds like you'd be better off using a single background thread instead of a timer.  The thread could enter your loop state until you signal that it's time to exit (in the `OnStop` method).

The new [Cancellation support in .NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/22/9635790.aspx) provides a fairly clean way to "cancel" your infinite loop...

Comment: Thanks Reed, yeah I just ended up using a background thread; having a Timer fire once seems like a misuse of the Timer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to be better off using a dedicated worker thread for that infinite loop. If you use some type of signaling mechanism like a `ManualResetEvent` to throttle the loop then you can cause it to stop as well.

```
public class YourService : ServiceBase
{
  private ManualResetEvent StopRequested = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
    new Thread(
      () =>
      {
        while (!StopRequested.WaitOne(0))
        {
          // Infinite loop code goes here.
        }
      }).Start();
  }

  protected override void OnStop()
  {
    StopRequested.Set();
  }
}
```

The nice thing about this pattern is that you can set the timeout parameter on `WaitOne` to adjust how long the loop waits between iterations. That basically gives you the same effect that I timer would.